# Relationship between countable set S, surjective and injective between $\mathbb{N}$ and S

Tags: real-analysis

I'm studying Real Analysis using Robert Bartle's text Elements of Real Analysis.

Wonder if I could get some help on understanding the proof of the following theorem:

The following statements are equivalent: 
(a) S is a countable set.
(b) There exists a surjection of $\Bbb{N}$ onto S.
(c) There exists an injection of S into $\Bbb{N}$

Proof. (a) $\Rightarrow$  (b) If $S$ is finite, there exists a bijection $h$ of some set $\Bbb{N}_n$ on $S$ and we define H on $\Bbb{N}$ by

$$
H(k) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            h(k) & \quad k = 1,...,n,  \\
            h(k) & \quad k > n
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

Then $H$ is a surjection of $\Bbb{N}$ onto $S$.

If $S$ is a denumerable, there exists a bijection $H$ of $\Bbb{N}$  onto $S$, which is also a surjection of $\Bbb{N}$  onto $S$.

Question:

The part of the proof that I do not understand is: $h(k)$ for $k>n$. Why is there a need for this piecewise of the function? How is it defined? In the sense that, if set $S = \text{{A,B,C,D}}$, then there exists a bijection $h$ of set $\Bbb{N}_4$ on $S$ (which is then, $H$ is a surjection of $\Bbb{N}$ onto $S$). Why then $h(k)$ for $k>n$? How to map a surjection of $\Bbb{N}$ onto $S$ for $k>4$ when $S$ only have 4 elements?

I feel like I'm missing a point here but couldn't quite point out what it is?

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly observe, it does not make sense to define $H(k)=h(k)$ for $k>n$ since $h(k)$ is not defined in that case.  I'm guessing this is just a typo, and it means to say $h(1)$ instead of $h(k)$ in that case.  That is, you pick some particular element of $S$ (say the first one according to $h$, namely $h(1)$) and define $H(k)$ to be that particular element for all $k>n$.

(Incidentally, there is still an error here: $h(1)$ is only defined if $n>0$.  Indeed, the statement being proved is not quite true: you need to assume $S$ is nonempty.  If $S$ is empty, then $S$ is countable, but there is no surjection $\mathbb{N}\to S$, since there is no function $\mathbb{N}\to S$ at all.)